# Styling different shapes in layers - Openlayers-3

Tags: openlayers, style, format

To add styling to Openlayers there seems to be different rules for different shapes.

I am trying to understand when to use what, but it is rather confusing and I am only able to do it with the help of examples.

For example, I have a few points generated on my map. I generated these points with GeoJSON data with the following format:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "property_a": 4,
            "property_b": 4234,
            "property_c": asdf,
            "property_d": 342342,
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [5.53204822887795, 51.609252234043296, 0.0]
        }
    }, etc...
```

I am trying to create points, polygon's and lines.
What I don't understand is to why every geometry needs it's own style contructors?

I created styling for a filled point with an example:

```
var _myStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
  color : 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
  width : 1,
});

var _myFill = new ol.style.Fill({
   color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
});

var circle = new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 5,
    fill: _myFill,
    stroke: _myStroke
}); 
var puntObjectenStyle = new ol.style.Style ({
   image:circle
});

var puntObjectenSource= new ol.source.Vector ({
  url: 'puntobjecten.json',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
var puntObjecten = new ol.layer.Vector ({
  source: puntObjectenSource,
  style: puntObjectenStyle
});
```

The documentation on the [Openlayers website](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html) doesnt even talk about the contructors ol.style.Circle, ol.style.Fill or ol.style.Stroke?

I have the following style-up for a polygon: (I don't even know if all these settings can be applied!)

```
 weight: '1.04',
 fillColor: '#da2122',
 color: '#000000',
 dashArray: '',
 opacity: '1.0',
 fillOpacity: '1.0',
```

How to create the correct functions to format a polygon?
And above all: how can I know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not looking at the right place. OpenLayers 3 (latest version) API docs are at http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/. It is, by the way, an excellent documentation.

You will use text field (top-left) to search for everything available in the library.

A [`ol.geom.Polygon`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html) can't be styled. You will apply a style to the feature that holds polygon.

Look at [`ol.style.Style`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.style.Style.html). There are 4 possibilities:

- `ol.style.Fill`;
- `ol.style.Image`;
- `ol.style.Stroke`;
- `ol.style.Text`;

So you can style a polygon like:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#b30734',
        width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [51, 51, 51, .7]
    })
});

var feature = new ol.Feature(
    new ol.geom.Polygon([[[-2e6, -1e6], [-1e6, 1e6],
            [0, -1e6], [-2e6, -1e6]]])
);
feature.setStyle(style);
```

[A demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/c30acpcu/).

Comment: Jonatas, you seem to answer exactly what I need to know. Now I am starting to understand how to read the documentation. You're awesome!!

Comment: Jonatas, you gave the hex value in stroke color and in rgba format format for fill color to add opacity. If I want to give the color in hex color code and opacity as well, then how do I do? `color: '#ff0000',0.5` or `color: ['#ff0000', 0.5]` does not work.

Comment: @LSG go with `color: [255, 0, 0, 0.5]`

Comment: I can't put the number values. I have to put the hex code. Anyway, I got an answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004153/setting-vector-feature-fill-opacity-when-you-have-a-hexadecimal-color/28033076